# Combine two (or more) value from an existing fields in DataStudio

Tags: formula, looker-studio

I cannot find a way to combine two value of an existing field in Google data studio.

My existing field is sub-status. Inside this field, I have many different sub-status (A,B,C,D and so on) that of course do not appear in my fields as they are sub-value of the field.

So I would like to combine two value of fields in my charts

```
sub-status = A , B , C, D ,E , f

value A = A + B
```

Answer (score 1):

I used [`REGEXP_MATCH`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7064476) to combine my sub status as
I wanted:

```
CASE
  WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(Sub Status, "(A|B)" ) THEN "C"
  WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(Sub Status, "(D|E)" ) THEN "F"
  WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(Sub Status, "(G)" ) THEN "H"
  WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(Sub Status, "(I)" ) THEN"J"
  ELSE 'K'
END
```

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, to answer the initial question, consolidating A and B to a single value, A, can be achieved using a [CASE Statement](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7020724):

```
CASE
  WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(sub-status, "A|B") THEN "A"
  ELSE sub-status
END
```

- Created a [Google Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/d4db9217-2cac-4236-a3f4-796f015dd080) (Google Sheets Embedded) to elaborate.

[image: A Visual of the Report]

Answer (score -1):

You can do it by click on table and after that choose on the right panel "add metric".

After that in the bottom of list choose "create metric".